# What is the correct implementation of the chain method of a Maybe Monad in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monads

I'm creating just for fun a simple Monad library in Typescript, following the wonderful specs at https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land.

Here the creator suggests **the three monadic laws**:

1. `M.of(a).chain(f)` is equivalent to `f(a)` (*left identity*)
2. `m.chain(M.of)` is equivalent to `m` (*right identity*)
3. `m.chain(f).chain(g)` is equivalent to `m.chain(x => f(x).chain(g))` (*associativity*)

So I implemented the test for the laws and this classic implementation.

```
import { setoid, functor, apply } from './common';

const isEmpty = (value: any) => value === null || value === undefined;

const chain = function<T, U>(fn: (val: T) => IMonad<U>) {  
  return this.isNone() ? this : fn(this.lift());
};

class Some<T> implements IMonad<T> {
  private _value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this._value = value;
  }

  lift = () => this._value;
  of = (value: T) => new Some(value);
  map = functor;
  ap = apply;
  flatMap = chain;
  equals = setoid;
  isSome = () => true
  isNone = () => false
}

class None implements IMonad<any> {
  constructor() {}

  lift = () => { throw "Cannot get a value from None" };
  of = (value: any) => new None();
  map = functor;
  ap = apply;
  flatMap = chain;
  equals = setoid;
  isSome = () => false;
  isNone = () => true;
}


class MaybeStatic implements IMonadStatic<any> {
  of = (value:any) => !isEmpty(value) ? new Some(value) : new None();
}

const maybeStatic = new MaybeStatic();

export { maybeStatic as Maybe, Some, None, MaybeStatic };
```

Running the test i saw that in the `None` case of the `Maybe` monad the *left identity* rule does not pass the test. In fact:

```
Maybe.of(null).chain(x => Some(x+2)) !== (null + 2)
```

In this case it seems that the fact that Js/Ts allow the operation null + 2 breaks the first monadic rule (where other languages probably do not allow this operation). I checked a lot of javascript and typescript implementation of the Maybe monad and they seem to completely ignore this problem.

So the questions:

- Why does it happen?
- Am I missing something?
- Is `x => Some(x+2)` a valid argument for a `None` or the chain should accept only functions that returns `None`?
- How can it be corrected?
- Should i take in account also for `NaN` (this could extend the maybe efficiency also for division by zero and other weird case like `undefined + 2`)?

**Edit**

- This anomaly seems to be present also in functional oriented language. I tried to implement a similar case in **Scala** [here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/mJQTZ88/0) using the native `Option` type.

Comment: Are you using a `null`/`undefined` value to encode the `None` case? You should use an explicit flag and ignore the value so you can implement `chain` as `return this._hasValue ? fn(this._value) : this`.

Comment: Please post your complete code, including how you implemented `of`, `lift`, and the `None` case

Comment: "*Is `x => Some(x+2)` a valid argument for `chain`?*" - yes, of course, its type is probably `int -> Maybe<int>`. But your `chain` method needs to work for *arbitrary* types, like `double -> Maybe<string>` (where the double value could be `NaN`) or also `null -> Maybe<object>`.

Comment: Thanks, i edited the post with the full implementation of the Maybe Monad.

Comment: `Some(x).isSome()` should yield `true` for *all* imaginable values and should never throw.

Comment: `IsSome` already does that. I could change it with simply true because the constructor forbids to build a Some with null or undefined.

`Some(x)` on the other hand should throw an error because i cannot instantiate a Some with a null or undefined value (many libraries implement it in this way). If you want to create a Some or None, you could use `Maybe.of(x)`.

Comment: No. `Some` should never throw, even with `null` or `undefined`. That's how algebraic data types work, and that's why your test fails. `Maybe.of` should always construct a `Some`.

Comment: Ok for never throwing. But the fact that Maybe.of should always construct a Some confuses me. It's not the entire point of creating a Maybe to not know if its result is a Some Or a None?

The library (https://github.com/cbowdon/TsMonad) for example implements the methods exactly as i did (including the exception)

Comment: `Maybe.of` must be `Some` to not violate the laws. Of course handling Maybes deals with both somethings and nothing, but the construction is always explicit. `of` means "wrap this value". A `None` doesn't wrap anything. You might want to implement something like `Maybe.fromNullable` as a helper method, but that has nothing to do with the monad.

Comment: In the library you mentioned, there is even an explicit "*Note that for Maybe, if the lifted function returns null or undefined then it returns Nothing rather than wrapping a null in a Just, which is perverse.*". This clearly shows that this is an exception to the rule, if one would follow the rules no note would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The `Maybe<T>` type(s) (or any generic type) should avoid inspecting their contained values and should operate only based on the structure defined by the constructors (in this case the `None<T>` and `Some<T>` classes).

Your `isSome` function violates this principle by checking for `null` and `undefined`. To comply with the monad laws, your `of` function should always return an instance of `Some` and your `chain` function should only check whether `this` is an instance of `Some` or `None`.

Within your `chain` function, `Some` instances can invoke the continuation function unconditionally with their inner value. `None<T>` instances always return `None` and so don't need to contain a value at all.

Putting these together, your implementation will look something like:

```
class Some<T> implements IMonad<T> {
  private _value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this._value = value;
  }

  of = (value: any) => new Some(value);
  chain = function<U>(fn: T => IMonad<U>) { return fn(this._value); };
  isSome = () => true;
  isNone = () => false;
}

class None<T> implements IMonad<T> {
  chain = function<U>(fn: T => IMonad<U>) { return new None<U>(); };
  isSome = () => false;
  isNone = () => true;
}

class MaybeStatic implements IMonadStatic<any> {
    of =(value:any) => new Some(value);
}
```

Comment: Your code confuses me. In your post you talk about a check to see if the monad is a `Some` in the chain method but there’s nothing about that. Is this a typo? 

Second, if the `Maybe.of` always returns a `Some`, 
the method  `Maybe.of(null).IsSome() ` returns true. This seems a little confusing for the end user.

Comment: @DavideMelfi - I posted that before you added the rest of your code to the question. Since `None` doesn't have a value it makes the `lift` function impossible to implement so I couldn't keep your `chain` implementation. Moving it to each subclass seemed like the simplest option. I'm not a typescript programmer though, so apologies if this has changed the meaning significantly.

Comment: As for it being confusing for the user, it might be if you think of `Maybe<T>` being a replacment for null, but it is just a structure which expresses zero-or-one items. This means that `Some(null)` makes sense in the same way the list `[null]` makes sense. You may want a function which lifts `null` and `undefined` to `None`, but you can't use `of` for this purpose since the monad laws require you to maintain the relationship with `chain`.

Comment: You might want to look at the [scala Option](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.5/src/library/scala/Option.scala) type which is structured similarly to yours. There `chain` is `flatMap` and `Maybe.of` is the `Some` constructor. `Option.apply` behaves similarly to your current `chain` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the advices and the Scala link. I will try to change my implementation following them and see if it fits the monadic rules.

Comment: Hi I tried to implement the Maybe as in Scala (I edited my original post), but the problem seems to still hold. My static `Maybe.of` method does the same as the constructor (`apply`) in Scala. My `chain` method is the equivalent of `flatMap`.

The problem arises when you apply a FlatMap with a `Some`.

Comment: @DavideMelfi - `Maybe.of` should always return a `Some`, so you should not inspect the argument e.g. `of(value) => Some(value)`. `of(null)` should return `Some(null)` and `of(undefined)` should return `Some(undefined)`.

Comment: I still don' get it, sorry (i'm surely missing something important) . I tried with this [Scala fiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/mJQTZ88/0) and the constructor of the `Option` monad (the equivalent of my `Maybe.of` static method) returns a `None`, not a `Some`.

In the fiddle you can also see the apparent violation of the `Left Identity` I was originally talking about.

Comment: @DavideMelfi - `Option.apply` in scala is not part of the option monad, it is just a utility function. The equivalent there of your `Maybe.of` function is the `Some` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this project to learn about monads then javascript may cause extra confusion with its dynamic types. If you're doing this because you want to use monads to write software then you may be overthinking the monad law. In any case the definition of equivalent is less stringent than javascript's ==. Here's one (incomplete) implementation of maybe in ts:

```
class MaybeInstance<T> {
    private isSome: boolean;
    private val: T;
    constructor(isSome: boolean, val: T) {
        this.isSome = isSome;
        this.val = val;
    }
    orJust(t: T) {
        return this.isSome
            ? this.val
            : t;
    }
    map<U>(fn: (t: T) => U): Maybe<U> {
        return new MaybeInstance<U>(this.isSome,
            this.isSome
                ? fn(this.val)
                : null);
    }
    chain<U>(fn: (t: T) => Maybe<U>): Maybe<U> {
        return this.isSome
            ? fn(this.val)
            : new MaybeInstance<U>(false, null);
    }
    isEquivalent<U>(mU: Maybe<U>) {
        return this.isSome === mU.isSome
            && typeof this.val === typeof mU.val;
    }
}

export type Maybe<T> = MaybeInstance<T>;

export module Maybe {

    export const some: <T>(val: T) => Maybe<T> =
        (val) => new MaybeInstance(true, val);

    export const none: () => Maybe<any> =
        () => new MaybeInstance(false, null);

    export const fromUndef: <T>(val: T | undefined) => Maybe<T> =
        (val) => !!val && (val as any) !== NaN
            ? some(val)
            : none();

}

const a = 1;
const f = (x: number) => Maybe.fromUndef(100 / x);
const g = (x: number) => Maybe.fromUndef(x).map(String);

const mA = Maybe.some(a);

console.log(
    // M.of(a).chain(f) is equivalent to f(a) (left identity)
    mA.chain(f).isEquivalent(f(a)),
    // m.chain(M.of) is equivalent to m (right identity)
    mA.chain(Maybe.some).isEquivalent(mA),
    // m.chain(f).chain(g) is equivalent to m.chain(x => f(x).chain(g)) (associativity)
    mA.chain(f).chain(g).isEquivalent(mA.chain((x) => f(x).chain(g))),
);
```

The ts compiler wont like this code with strict null checks on (but isn't maybe a strict enough null check?) and its missing a lot of functions such as ap, concat, etc but it shows that defining useful adts in ts is easy enough.